# Dynamic Created Element In iE9 Event doesnot work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, setattribute, createelement

```
var ibutton = document.createElement('input');
ibutton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
ibutton.setAttribute('name', 'button');
ibutton.setAttribute('value', 'Delete');
ibutton.setAttribute('onclick', "deleteImage('<?php echo $_FILES['dt_file']['name'];?>', this,'<?php echo $image_type;?>');return false;");`
```

The above code creates a delete button. This works fine only for the latest created button.

When I click and select an image, the image is created dynamically with this button, but every time I click and select an image the event `onclick` only works for the latest created button. All the element created before have no working events, but it does not display any errors.

The above code works fine in Mozilla, but not in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You are using eval on setAttribute, maybe thats why it's not working.

But you can avoid eval (and it's a good practice to do that) with something like this:

```
var ibutton = document.createElement('input');
ibutton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
ibutton.setAttribute('name', 'button');
ibutton.setAttribute('value', 'Delete');
ibutton.onclick = function() { deleteImage.apply(this, '<?php echo $_FILES['dt_file']['name'];?>', this,'<?php echo $image_type;?>');return false };`
```

if you use `this` will refer to ibutton inside your deleteImage function.

Comment: function deleteImage is already there in other javascript file which I have included . But here in setAttribute the deleteImage is getting the parameters .

Comment: Edited to apply the deleteImage function, with this scope and parans you need.